# Why I can't see my custom app I created in Odoo?

Tags: python, xml, odoo

so I've been trying to learn Odoo16 development, and I'm following the documentation, but the problem is, after I enable the `access rights` i can't see my custom app in the general settings.

This is my directory.

[image]

models.py

```
from odoo import fields, models

class RealEstate(models.Model):
    _name = 'estate_property'
    _description = 'Real Estate Property'

    name = fields.Char(string="Name", required=True)
    description = fields.Text(string="Description")
    postcode = fields.Char(string="Postcode")
    date_availability = fields.Date(string="Date")
    expected_price = fields.Float(string="Expected Price",  required=True)
    selling_price = fields.Float(string="Selling Price", required=True)
    bedrooms = fields.Integer(string="Bedrooms")
    living_area = fields.Integer(string="Living Area")
    facades = fields.Integer(string="Facades")
    garage = fields.Boolean(string="Garage")
    garden = fields.Boolean(string="Garden")
    garden_area = fields.Integer(string="Garden Area")
    garden_orientation = fields.Selection(
        string="Garden Orientation",
        selection=[('north', 'North'), ('east','East'), ('south','South'), ('west','west') ]
    )
```

**manifest**.py

```
{
    "name": "Estate",  # The name that will appear in the App list
    "version": "16.0",  # Version
    "application": True,  # This line says the module is an App, and not a module
    "depends": ["base"],  # dependencies
    "data": [
        'security/ir.model.access.csv',
        'views/estate_property_views.xml',
        'views/estate_menus.xml'
    ],
    "installable": True,
    'license': 'LGPL-3',
}
```

**ir.model.access.csv**

```
id,name,model_id:id,group_id:id,perm_read,perm_write,perm_create,perm_unlink
estate.access_estate_property,access_estate_property,estate.model_estate_property,base.group_user,1,1,1,1
```

Upon further searching, I read that I should commment/uncomment xml files, but it still doesn't work.

estate_menus.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
    <data>
        <menuitem id="estate_menu_root" name="Estate Property">
            <menuitem id="estate_first_level_menu" name="First Level">
                <menuitem id="estate_property_menu_action" action="estate_property_action"/>
            </menuitem>
        </menuitem>

    </data>
</odoo>
```

estate_property_views.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
    <data>
        <record id="estate_property_action" model="ir.actions.act_window">
            <field name="name">Properties</field>
            <field name="res_model">estate_property</field>
            <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
        </record>
    </data>
</odoo>
```

I'm stuck at this problem right now, I tried changing to `superuser` but it works one time, but once i refresh my browser, the custom apps will disappear

**Addition**

this is my odoo.conf

```
[options]
admin_passwd = $pbkdf2-sha512$25000$7N07x/hf670XwvjfG2OMsQ$4bzF6iN4y0uxX3o915LeEAznINV1e8bZMf1c6rkyOX4Q5UfZE5uMYsvQwiY89IIZ2b61izNr3uVqEnbV3b6kxQ
db_host = localhost
db_port = 5432
db_user = admin
db_password = admin
addons_path = addons , customaddons
http_port = 8015
```

Answer (score 1):

Share your addons path and also create tree and form then check

Comment: Hello, I created the config, right now, im still learning tree and form so im sorry if i can't provide you more details

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).